# what is the meaning of "wearing a shirt"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

[image: stick figure drawing of someone with a shirt on and someone putting their arms through the sleeves of a shirt]

Who is wearing a shirt?
 I think number 1 man is wearing a shirt.
 But my mothertongue also makes sense number 2 man is wearing a shirt.

I think that "wearing a shirt"can transplate  a double meaning .  which is  a man is wearing his clothes all day. (1 number picture) And  wearing his clothes just that moment. (2 number picture) and  I edit my picture because number 2 picture look like put off his shirts.

And I don’t  know why I can’t  comment.

Comment: Cute drawing. What did your English dictionary tell you about the verb *to wear*?

Comment: Man #1 is *wearing* his shirt. Man #2 appears to be *putting on* his shirt.

Comment: Is the second picture of the man putting his arms through the arms of the shirt, like an activity, or is it just the beginning of wearing the shirt all day?
 What  is your native language and does it distinguish among those three pictures? Maybe [this ELU question about tense and aspect might help](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is "wear a shirt"

2 is "put on a shirt"

-ing seems to be attached to wearing.

So wearing is like a progression form.

It is right in a sense.

but wearing is almost a complement.

"wear" can be used like here.

He wears a mustache.

He wears a shirt.

What is difference between "wears a shirt" and "is wearing a shirt"?

"is wearing a shirt" is temporarily,for a short time  but after putting it on.

"wears a shirt" is relatively,for a long time after putting it on.

"put on" is not used after putting on a shirt,it is an action has a finis!

I wear new suits to the party.
(It is not that I am putting on new suits on the way to the party as I get to near the place, as time goes! it means that I put on new suits and go to the party!)

I'm wearing new suits to the party.

It makes no sense.

It means that I wear new suits temporarily, and put it off, and go to the party.
you probably go to the party with naked or under shirts.

Comment: That didn't help at all. Now you have the poor person wearing plural _suits_  to a party and you're still insisting this can be done in the present tense simple. Except for certain statal verbs, _the present tense simple is never used to describe what's happening now._